# How create invalidation in aws cloudfront after action in my elixir/phoenix project

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, amazon-cloudfront

I use the `ex_aws` dependency in my elixir/phoenix project to make some actions in my aws account. Now I need to run something like this to invalidate the cache:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id 1111111111 --paths '/*'
```

But the `ex_aws` dependency doesn't have the cloudfront service. Any solutions for this?

```
Versions:
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.0"}
      ...
      {:ex_aws, "~> 2.1.0"},
      {:ex_aws_s3, "~> 2.0.1"},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not try to cover all the functionality AWS provides via pure Elixir wrappers. Erlang (and hence Elixir) both are built to maintain a very good interaction level with the underlying OS and [`System.cmd/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/System.html#cmd/3) is the first class citizen. So,

```
System.cmd(
  "aws",
  ~w|cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id 1111111111 --paths '/*'|,
  env: [{"MIX_ENV", "prod"}])
```